# Formatting User Form Controls

Tags: vba, foreach, formatting, controls, userform

I am trying to format controls on each of my User Forms similarly, but what I have formats all controls on a User Form instead of just the labels or just the textboxes.

Here is what I have:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

FormatUserForms UFNewRequest

End Sub

Sub FormatUserForms(UF As UserForm)

UF.BackColor = RGB(51, 51, 102)

For Each Label In UF.Controls
    Label.BackColor = RGB(51, 51, 102)
    Label.ForeColor = RGB(247, 247, 247)
Next

For Each Button In UF.Controls
    Button.BackColor = RGB(247, 247, 247)
    Button.ForeColor = RGB(0, 0, 0)
Next

For Each TextBox In UF.Controls
    TextBox.BackColor = RGB(247, 247, 247)
    TextBox.ForeColor = RGB(0, 0, 0)
Next

End Sub
```

This sort of does what I want, but each For Each overwrites the last. Is there anyway to delineate Controls in a User Form so that they are not overwritten?

Also, every time I open my and then close my User Forms with this, I get an "out of memory" error. Help with that would be appreciated as well! Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't check, but the "out of memory" error is most likely related to using the default instance of the `UserForm` in its own `Initialize` procedure:

```
FormatUserForms UFNewRequest
```

You shouldn't do that (and don't need to).  You can always get a reference to the form in its code-behind with `Me`.  I'd remove that entirely.  As for the controls, you can call `TypeName` to figure out what type of control it is, and then use a `Select Case` to format them accordingly:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    FormatUserForms
End Sub

Sub FormatUserForms()
    Me.BackColor = RGB(51, 51, 102)
    Dim current As Control

    For Each current In Me.Controls
        Select Case TypeName(current)
            Case "Label"
                current.BackColor = RGB(51, 51, 102)
                current.ForeColor = RGB(247, 247, 247)
            Case "CommandButton"
                current.BackColor = RGB(247, 247, 247)
                current.ForeColor = RGB(0, 0, 0)
            Case "TextBox"
                current.BackColor = RGB(247, 247, 247)
                current.ForeColor = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for this. It looks like TypeName and Select Case are what I needed to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2):

You are looping over all Controls three times, so every call changes color for all controls. Naming a variable `Textbox` doesn't filter the controls for only textboxes.
You have to separate the Controls types by using `TypeName(ctrl)`:

```
For Each ctrl In u.Controls
    If TypeName(ctrl) = "TextBox" Then
        ctrl.BackColor = ...
    ElseIf TypeName(ctrl) = "Label" Then
        ctrl.BackColor = ...
    Else
        ...
    End If
next ctrl
```

As far as I see, this works only if the form is open, so put a call to your function into the `UserForm_Initialize`-Event.