# Permanently Changing User Forms

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I am trying to permanently change a UserForm so that I only have to run the code once instead of it being run every time the button to open the UserForm is clicked.

I found that this works for some people. I am not sure what might be wrong for me.

```
Sub FormatUserForms(UF As UserForm)

UF.BackColor = RGB(51, 51, 102)
Dim ctrl As Control

With ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("UFNewRequest").Designer
    For Each ctrl In UF.Controls
        Select Case TypeName(ctrl)
            Case "Label"
                ctrl.BackColor = RGB(51, 51, 102)
                ctrl.ForeColor = RGB(247, 247, 247)
            Case "CommandButton"
                ctrl.BackColor = RGB(247, 247, 247)
                ctrl.ForeColor = RGB(0, 0, 0)
            Case "TextBox"
                ctrl.BackColor = RGB(247, 247, 247)
                ctrl.ForeColor = RGB(0, 0, 0)
            Case "OptionButton"
                ctrl.BackColor = RGB(51, 51, 102)
                ctrl.ForeColor = RGB(247, 247, 247)
        End Select
    Next
End With
End Sub

Sub formatting()

FormatUserForms UFNewRequest

End Sub
```

Comment: So, what's the question?

Comment: BTW if that code is in the form's code-behind, drop the `UF` parameter and use `Me` instead, [as you were told yesterday](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42421855/1188513). `FormatUserForms UFNewRequest` is sending **the default instance**, which is **not necessarily the instance that's currently executing**.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why would you want to change the control properties in the stored binary stream of the form?  Setting them dynamically adds very minimal overhead to the form load and is ***way*** more flexible and maintainable if you decide that the `TextBox` background color needs to be a couple shades lighter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing two things. It's the right track to use the `ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("UFNewRequest").Designer` object, but you're not using it. Instead, your code works on the form passed as parameter - and this will work only at runtime.

```
Sub FormatUserForm(frm As Object)

Dim d As UserForm
Set d = frm.Designer

d.BackColor = RGB(51, 51, 102)

Dim ctrl As Control
For Each ctrl In d.Controls
    Select Case TypeName(ctrl)
            (...)
    End Select
Next ctrl

End Sub
```

You can call the function for all forms on your project:

```
Dim f As Object
For Each f In ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents
    If f.Type = 3 Then
       Call FormatUserForm(f)
    End If
Next f
```

I guess there is a way to use early binding for f, but you have to add a reference to VBE to your project and I'm not allowed to do this on my computer so I cannot test. Probably there is a Constant defined for the magic type number 3 (=forms) also

Comment: I think this is what I am looking for, especially the ability to call the function for all forms on my project, but Set d = frm.designer is giving me the error "Object doesn't support this property or method." Any ideas?